# Finding a way to stop null pointer dereferencing

Tags: c, linked-list

I've been trying to figure out where i'm dereferencing a null pointer in a doubly linked list bubble sort in C. While specifically adding `while(p2->next!=NULL)` I get `Exception thrown: read access violation.p2->**next** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.`

```
node* swap(node* p1, node* p2) 
{
    p1->next = p2->next;
    p2->next->prev = p2->prev;//Exception thrown: read access violation.
    // p2->**next** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

    free(p2);
    return p1;
}
void sort_list(node** head, int n) {
    node** ptr = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            node* p1 = *ptr;
            node* p2 = p1->next;
            while (p2->next != NULL) {
                if (p1->data > p2->data) {
                    p1=swap(p1, p2);
                }
                else { p1 = p1->next;}
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please give me a hint on how to solve this? (maybe reccomend something I can read up on concerning this topic as I'm learning on my own and I dont have anyone to help me when i'm stuck) I also get a couple of warnings about dereferencing null pointer in function that creates the head node and in other function that creates the rest of the nodes

```
node* add_to_empty(node* head, int data)//creates the 1st node and returns head pointer to it
{
    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    return head;
}
node* add_at_beg(node* head, int data)//adds node in front of the last one
{
    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->next = head;
    head->prev = temp;
    head = temp;
    return head;}
```

What is usually done to avoid these warnings?

Comment: Please provide a [example]

Comment: `p2->next->prev`... What happens if `p2->next` is an invalid (e.g. null) pointer?

Comment: What happens if `p2` is a null pointer in `while (p2->next != NULL)` ?

Comment: And your function `swap` is really badly named. It doesn't swap anything, but attempt to unlink a node.

Comment: By the way, you have a loop `while (p2->next != NULL)`, but nowhere inside the loop do you modify `p2`.

Comment: Step through the code using a debugger and watch the pointer variables. Very likely the current one is null, and so the next one after that will be gibberish.

Comment: If you have a choice of sorting algorithm, sorting a linked list would be *way* easier using a merge sort (while still being a good exercise)

Comment: When it comes to lists, or other linked data-structures, I recommend you solve it all using pencil and paper first. Draw nodes as labeled boxes, and links/pointers as arrows. Erase and redraw arrows as you modify the links/pointers. Make it work on paper first, then implement it in code. If something goes wrong in the code, use pencil and paper for the debugging as well, erasing and redrawing as needed. And compare it to what you had before.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just going to look at `swap` because that's the error you asked about and because there's lots to unpack there. The rest of the code fares no better, but I'm going to have to leave that out of scope.

---

**Normal case**

```
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
head-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->NULL
NULL<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--tail
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
                    ^                   ^
                    |                   |
                    p1                  p2
```

To swap p1 and p2, we need to update

- p1->prev and p1->next.
- p2->prev and p2->next.
- p1->prev->next.
- p1->next->prev.
- p2->prev->next.
- p2->next->prev.

Eight assignments are needed, but you only have two!

And we also need to consider edge cases. There are two:

- p1->prev is NULL, which is to say p1 is the first node of the list.
- p2->next is NULL, which is to say p2 is the last node of the list.

Because p1 and p2 are always going to be different, and because p2 will always come later than p1 in the list, neither p1->next nor p2->prev will ever be NULL.

If p1 and p2 are adjacent, some of the assignments will be redundant, but that's no reason to treat the case specially.

---

**p1 is the first node of the list**

```
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
head-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->NULL
NULL<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--tail
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
          ^                             ^
          |                             |
          p1                            p2
```

To swap p1 and p2, we need to update

- p1->prev and p1->next.
- p2->prev and p2->next.
- <strike>p1->prev->next</strike> head.
- p1->next->prev.
- p2->prev->next.
- p2->next->prev.

---

**p2 is the last node of the list**

```
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
head-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->NULL
NULL<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--tail
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
                    ^                             ^
                    |                             |
                    p1                            p2
```

To swap p1 and p2, we need to update

- p1->prev and p1->next.
- p2->prev and p2->next.
- p1->prev->next.
- p1->next->prev.
- p2->prev->next.
- <strike>p2->next->prev</strike> tail.

---

Keep in mind that both edge cases could happen in the same call.

```
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
head-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->NULL
NULL<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--|     |<--tail
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
          ^                                       ^
          |                                       |
          p1                                      p2
```

To swap p1 and p2, we need to update

- p1->prev and p1->next.
- p2->prev and p2->next.
- <strike>p1->prev->next</strike> head.
- p1->next->prev.
- p2->prev->next.
- <strike>p2->next->prev</strike> tail.

Answer (score 1):

Null pointer dereferences are commonly caused by snippets of code like this:

```
node* p2 = p1->next;
while (p2->next != NULL)
```

What if `p1->next` is `NULL` ? In that case, you assign `NULL` to `p2` and *immediately dereference it* with the expression `p2->next`.

One commonly-used pattern to protect against this sort of problem:

```
while (p2 != NULL && p2->next != NULL)
```

One of the benefits of the `&&` operator is that it "short circuits" — if the left hand expression (`p2 != NULL`) evaluates to false, the entire expression must evaluate to false, and so *the right hand expression is not evaluated*. In other words, the pointer will not be dereferenced if it is NULL.

I'm not saying that this is the correct logic for your particular use case, but this pattern is very useful as a basic tool when using pointers that might be NULL.

Comment: I agree with you in general.  However, in this particular case I observe that if the function's parameter `n` correctly conveys the number of nodes in the list, as the function seems to assume, then the assignment to `p2` is reached only when the list has at least two elements, in which case neither `p1` nor `p1->next` is null.

Comment: @John Bollinger, There's the question of whether `n` should even exist, though.

Comment: Absolute true, @ikegami, but as long as it does exist and the function is using it as it does, the issue discussed in this answer does not apply to the code in question.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing :)

Answer (score 1):

Your routine has numerous issues.

Starting with `swap()`:

- you don't actually need a general swap at all.  You need only a swap-with-next, which can be simpler.
- your swap does not swap.  In the event that the first and second arguments point to successive elements in the list, it removes the second from the list and deallocates it.  This is **not** what you want where you are using this function.

  - and if the first and second arguments did not point to successive elements in the list then not only would this function deallocate a node, but it would also corrupt the list.
- your swap function always returns its first argument.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that, but it doesn't do anything useful for you, either.

Continuing with `sort_list()`:

- The function is structured as if to perform *n* times as much work as it needs to do on account of having an extra level of loop.
- Linked-list functions ordinarily do not accept or depend on a pre-specified length parameter.  You can use one if you like, I guess, but if you do then you should do it consistently.
- your `while` loop condition depends on `p2->next`, but `p2->next` is not modified within that loop, except inasmuch as `*p2` might be deallocated (see above).

---

Honestly, there's not much worth saving there.  I would scrap it and restart from scratch.  In doing so, consider

1. You can largely avoid special cases by temporarily giving your list a dummy head node.  Framework for that:

   ```
   void sort_list(node **head) {
       node dummy = { .next = *head };

       if (dummy.next) {  // else an empty list
           dummy.next->prev = &dummy;

           // ... perform the sort.  Every pass starts at dummy.next ...

           dummy.next->prev = NULL;
       }

       *head = dummy.next;
   }
   ```

   With that, your real head node has a predecessor for the interim.
2. As already hinted, do not depend on an externally-provided list length.  You can avoid that, among other ways, by maintaining a pointer representing the head of the sorted tail list, and terminating each swap pass when you reach the predecessor of the current tail (which then becomes the new head of the tail list).  You will then know that there are no more passes to be done when the real list head (the dummy head's successor if you implement (1)) is also the head of the tail list.
3. Instead of a general swap, implement a `swap_with_next()`, which is a bit simpler.  If you implement (1) then `swap_with_next()` does not need to account for the possibility of a null predecessor, but it will still need to watch out for `next->next` being null.